# Need help with MPMoviePlayerController initialization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an app that allows the user to move from a list of media items to a specific item using the drill-down table view model.

[image: Main View]

Once the user is inside the detail view, another table view exists allowing the user to select a specific media item.

[image: Detail View]

I am having an issue creating a modal media player to play the .mp4 items.  The code below is what I have so far.

```
if (indexPath.section == SectionHeader && indexPath.row == SectionHeaderEnclosure) {  
    if (item.enclosures) {  
        for (NSDictionary *dict in item.enclosures){ 

            NSString *url = [dict objectForKey:@"url"];  
            NSLog(@" url is : %@",url); 

            //EXPERIMENTAL
            MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];  

            // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.  
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];  

            if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {  
                // Use the 3.2 style API  
                moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;  
                moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;  
                [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];  
                [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];  
            } else {  
                // Use the 2.0 style API  
                moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;  
                [moviePlayer play];  
            }           
        }  
    }  
}
```

I need help with this line:
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

It is giving me an NSInvaild Argument Exception.  I need help with the video player creation and subsequent deletion from the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the URL stored as a plain `NSString`, whereas the player expects an `NSURL`. How about this?

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
    initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```